# Record by record timestamp difference calculation

Tags: apache-spark, hive, timestamp, spark-streaming, summarization

I am working on a logic to find the consecutive time difference between two timestamps in the streaming layer(spark) by comparing the previous time and current time and storing the value in the database.

For eg:

1. 2017-08-01 11:00:00
2. 2017-08-01 11:05:00
3. 2017-08-01 11:07:00

So according to the above timestamps my consecutive diff will be 5 mins(11:00:00 - 11:05:00) and 2 mins respectively and when i sum the difference I will get 7 mins(5+2) which will be actual time difference.. Now the real challenge is when I receive delayed timestamp.

For eg:

1. 2017-08-01 11:00:00
2. 2017-08-01 11:05:00
3. 2017-08-01 11:07:00
4. 2017-08-01 11:02:00

Here when i calculate the difference it will be 5 mins,2 mins,5 mins  respectively and now sum of the difference I will get 12 mins(5+2+5) which will be greater than the actual time difference(7 mins).which is wrong

please help me to find a workaround to handle this delayed timestamp in record by record time difference calculation.

Comment: you could sort on timestamp then calculate difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the difference between 'event time' and 'processing time'. In the best case, processing time will be nearly identical to event time, but sometimes, an input record is delayed, so the difference will be larger.

When you process streaming data, you define (explicitly or implicitly) a *window* of records that you look at. If you process records individually, this window has size 1. In your case, your window has size 2. But you could also have a window that is based on time, i.e. you can look at all records that have been received in the last 10 minutes.

If you want to process delayed records in-order, you need to wait before the delayed records have arrived and then sort the records within the window. The problem then becomes, how long do you wait? The delayed records may show up 2 days later! How long to wait is a subjective question and depends on your application and its requirements.

Note that if your window is time-based, you will need to handle the case where no previous record is available.

I highly recommend this article: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101 to get to grips with streaming terminology and windows.

Comment: thanks for the response.. will go through the article and come back..thanks a lot